# How many methods can we reasonably put in an entity before it's considered bloated?

Tags: oop, methods, properties, domain-driven-design, single-responsibility-principle

With all those readings about single responsibility principle, decomposition, etc., it's difficult to get an idea of what should be the alarm signal that an entity gets bloated.

Is there some good advice/reading somewhere about how many methods we should consider a maximum, or if there are some objective other criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles should be treated as guidelines, not as strict rules. SOLID violation is usually a reliable indicator of a design issue. But they are unavoidable sometimes.

There are quite a few code metrics. From [NDepends](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbMethods):

> NbMethods: (defined for application, assemblies, namespaces, types)
>   The number of methods. A method can be an abstract, virtual or
>   non-virtual method, a method declared in an interface, a constructor,
>   a class constructor, a finalizer, a property/indexer getter or setter,
>   an event adder or remover. Methods declared in third-party assemblies
>   are not taken account.
>
> Recommendations: **Types where NbMethods > 20 might be hard to
>   understand** and maintain but there might be cases where it is relevant
>   to have a high value for NbMethods. For example, the
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView third-party class has more than 1000
>   methods.

20 is what NDepends authors considered to be a reasonable threshold. Here is another opinion from [objecteering](http://support.objecteering.com/objecteering6.1/help/us/metrics/metrics_in_detail/number_of_methods.htm):

> This value should remain **between 3 and 7**.  This would indicate that a
>   class has operations, but not too many.  A value greater than 7 may
>   indicate the need for further object-oriented decomposition, or that
>   the class does not have a coherent purpose.  A value of 2 or less
>   indicates that this is not truly a class, but merely a data
>   construction.

As you can see these metrics are quite subjective. So you have to decide what makes sense for you and your team. From DDD perspective I found that using [Value Objects](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/135) is a very good approach to reduce SRP violations on Entities.

Comment: Interesting documentation. It's maybe not only subjective, but also depending on the context. If you're designing entities, 3 to 7 looks somewhat unreachable! And +1 for using value objects when possible.